How to resolve error can not found tools.jar
Execution failed for task ':API:compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51 contains a valid JDK installation.
Editor : Intellij
I tried to compile minecraft plugin support 1.8-1.21 but couldn't fix it. I don't know what happened.
I tried to fix the problem myself many times, such as fixing the project structure, fixing the SDK, but it was not possible.
I've tried solving the problem so that it compiles only the version that doesn't require tools.jar. In order to compile it, it still needs tools.jar.

This question is similar to: Unable to locate tools.jar. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are trying to compile with a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) instead of a JDK (Java Development Kit). You have to change it.

Download and install JDK from here. You can also install more recent JDK here (as newer version of Java. Java 8 is 10 years old now).

You have to add it in eclipse. To do this, you can go to "Window -> Preference", then in the menu, go to "Java", and click on "Installed JREs". Now, you can add the new JDK with the button "Add".


Example of result (my own installation) :


If it's not detected by gradle, add this to your file gradle.properties :

org.gradle.java.home=C:\\url\\to\\jdk

